# Failed to deploy a full-stack project with Nodejs in backend and ReactJs in frontend to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have a full-stack  project's working directory looks like:

> |__ server 
>   | 
>   |__ client 
>   | 
>   |__ node_modules 
>   | 
>   |__ package.json

- In folder server is a NodeJs for backend
- In folder client is a ReacJs for frontend
- Here is the code in package.json in the root folder:

```
{
  "name": "kmail",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "server": "cd server && npm start",
    "start": "concurrently - kill-others \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "3.5.1"
  }
}
```

When I run the project locally, it works fine. However, when I deploy it to Heroku, it failed and here is the logs I got:

```
Starting process with command 'npm start'
concurrently - kill-others "npm run server" "npm run client"
concurrently - kill-others: not found
```

Do you know any solution to fix this? Or is there any host service other than Heroku that can help to solve my problem?
Thank you very much.

Comment: This [answer I just posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504768/deploy-the-backend-and-frontend-on-the-same-heroku-app-dyno/61354113#61354113) to a similar question, using a proxy and a heroku-postbuild step, would allow you to deploy to Heroku as one app (but also run it locally with one command, through concurrently).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy the backend and frontend on the same Heroku app/dyno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504768/deploy-the-backend-and-frontend-on-the-same-heroku-app-dyno)

Answer (score 0):

Well, "start" script should start the server part

```
"start": "node index.js --prefix server"
```

Heroku looks for "start" script and actualy use it to run the app.

Try changing it, and if error persist paste the whole log here

Answer (score 0):

I think is `--kill-others` not `- kill-others`

```
"start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
```