# Deploy Heroku with App has more than 1 running command

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, server, peerjs

currently i want to deploy an app on Heroku and my app has 2 running commands like this:

[image: img]

the command `npm run devStart` is for my server and `peerjs --port 3001` is for server API of PeerJs, now i want to deploy my app on Heroku, please give me a step by step guide to deploy it ( i am totally a newbie with heroku)

Thank you so much and have a good day :)

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504768/deploy-the-backend-and-frontend-on-the-same-heroku-app-dyno

Comment: You can use Concurrently. An npm package for running multiple commands concurrently

Comment: Or you could use npm-run-all an npm package for running commands/scripts in sequence or in parallel

Comment: thank you Rilla, it worked, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can design an executable and put the two commands in it like this:

```
command 1
time.sleep()
command 2
```

And then assign the executable to the dyno worker(in heroku) by making a Procfile(file named Procfile) with the following line of code(assuming you named the executable file 'exec'):

```
worker: ./exec
```

Comment: thank you so much, i am able to handle it by the way of Rilla, thank you anyway