# Is there a way to deploy client/server from two repositories on Heroku

Tags: heroku, client-server

I have two git repositories for client and server side code. I already deployed them individually on heroku. Is there a way to connect them on Heroku please?

Comment: Any specific reason why you need to connect them to the same app?

Comment: I use react front for client side and node js for backend both on different git repositories. They both run on different containers on heroku. I am seeking for a way to merge them to one container on heroku

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36504768/deploy-the-backend-and-frontend-on-the-same-heroku-app-dyno